# My main.dart code does not return the tasks from calendar.dart

Tags: flutter, dart

So my main.dart code is the homepage of my app and calendar.dart is a page I want to have retrieved as CalendarRoute. The calendar.dart code is correct as the tasks are returned when I put the same code of calendar.dart in my main.dart. So in calendar.dart there is no specific problem but I think that the widget CalendarRoute with which I retrieve the code as a page of main.dart can not access the tasks. I have the _showTasks function in the widget HomePage which is the home of CalendarRoute. Maybe that is where the problem is.
Any advice on how to successfully connect CalendarRoute with calendar.dart and also show the tasks are welcome!

main.dart:

```
void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    theme: ThemeData(
      primaryColor: Colors.white,
    ),
    initialRoute: '/',
    routes: {
      '/': (context) => const HomeRoute(),
      '/settings': (context) => const SettingsRoute(),
      '/profile': (context) => ProfilePage(),
      '/calendar': (context) => const CalendarRoute(),
      '/activity': (context) => const ActivityRoute(),
    },
  ));
}


class HomeRoute extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeRoute({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeRouteState createState() => _HomeRouteState();
}

class _HomeRouteState extends State<HomeRoute> {
  int _currentIndex = 0;

  final List<Widget> _pages = [
    HomeRouteContent(),
    const ActivityRoute(),
    const CalendarRoute(),
    const SettingsRoute(),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: _currentIndex == 0
          ? AppBar(
              title: const Text("Home"),
              centerTitle: true,
              backgroundColor: Colors.black,
            )
          : null,
      body: _pages[_currentIndex],
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      bottomNavigationBar: CurvedNavigationBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        color: Colors.black,
        animationDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
        index: _currentIndex,
        onTap: (index) {
          setState(() {
            _currentIndex = index;
          });
        },
        items: [
          Icon(Icons.home, color: Colors.white),
          Icon(Icons.bar_chart_outlined, color: Colors.white),
          Icon(Icons.calendar_today, color: Colors.white),
          Icon(Icons.settings, color: Colors.white),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HomeRouteContent extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeRouteContent();

  @override
  _HomeRouteContentState createState() => _HomeRouteContentState();
}

class _HomeRouteContentState extends State<HomeRouteContent> {
  int _currentSlide = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          SizedBox(height: 10),
          CarouselSliderWidget(
            initialSlide: _currentSlide,
            onPageChanged: (index) {
              setState(() {
                _currentSlide = index;
              });
            },
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 10),
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              final homeRouteState =
                  context.findAncestorStateOfType<_HomeRouteState>();
              homeRouteState?.setState(() {
                homeRouteState._currentIndex = 1;
              });
            },
            child: ActivityWidget(
              value: 80,
              onTap: () {
                final homeRouteState =
                    context.findAncestorStateOfType<_HomeRouteState>();
                homeRouteState?.setState(() {
                  homeRouteState._currentIndex = 1;
                });
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

calendar.dart:

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await DBHelper.initDb();
  await GetStorage.init();
  runApp(const CalendarRoute());
}

class CalendarRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  const CalendarRoute({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
        title: 'Calendar',
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: Themes.light,
        darkTheme: Themes.dark,
        themeMode: ThemeMode.light,
        home: const HomePage()); //ruft HomePage ab mit _showTasks
  }
}

// Colors
const Color bluishClr = Color(0xFF4e5ae8);
const Color yellowClr = Color(0xFFFFb746);
const Color pinkClr = Color(0xFFff4667);
const Color white = Colors.white;
const primaryClr = darkGreyClr;
const Color darkGreyClr = Color(0xFF121212);
Color darkHeaderClr = Color(0xFF424242);

// Themes
class Themes {
  static final light = ThemeData(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      primaryColor: primaryClr,
      brightness: Brightness.light);
  static final dark = ThemeData(
      backgroundColor: darkGreyClr,
      primaryColor: darkGreyClr,
      brightness: Brightness.dark);
}

// Text Style
TextStyle get subHeadingStyle {
  return GoogleFonts.lato(
      textStyle: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 24,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          color: Get.isDarkMode ? Colors.grey[400] : Colors.grey));
}

TextStyle get headingStyle {
  return GoogleFonts.lato(
      textStyle: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 30,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          color: Get.isDarkMode ? Colors.white : Colors.black));
}

TextStyle get titleStyle {
  return GoogleFonts.lato(
      textStyle: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 16,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          color: Get.isDarkMode ? Colors.white : Colors.black));
}

TextStyle get buttonStyle {
  return GoogleFonts.lato(
      textStyle: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white));
}

TextStyle get subTitleStyle {
  return GoogleFonts.lato(
      textStyle: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 14,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          color: Get.isDarkMode ? Colors.grey[100] : Colors.grey[600]));
}

//
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  DateTime _selectedDate = DateTime.now();
  final _taskController = Get.put(TaskController());
  var notifyHelper;
  late BuildContext scaffoldContext; // Hinzugefügte Zeile

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    notifyHelper = NotifyHelper();
    notifyHelper.initializeNotification();
    notifyHelper.requestIOSPermissions();
    _taskController.getTasks(); // Fetch tasks when the HomePage is initialized
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    scaffoldContext = context;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: _appBar(),
      backgroundColor: context.theme.backgroundColor,
      body: Column(
        children: [
          _addTaskBar(),
          _addDateBar(),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 10),
          _showTasks(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  _showTasks() {
    return Expanded(
      child: Obx(() {
        return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: _taskController.taskList.length,
            itemBuilder: (_, index) {
              Task task = _taskController.taskList[index];
              //print(task.toJson());
              if(task.repeat=='Daily') {
              DateTime date = DateFormat.jm().parse(task.startTime.toString());
              var myTime =DateFormat('HH:mm').format(date);
              notifyHelper.scheduledNotification(
                int.parse(myTime.toString().split(':')[0]),
                int.parse(myTime.toString().split(':')[1]),
                task
 
              );
              return AnimationConfiguration.staggeredList(
                position: index,
                child: SlideAnimation(
                    child: FadeInAnimation(
                  child: Row(children: [
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        _showBottomSheet(
                            context, task);
                      },
                      child: TaskTile(task),
                    )
                  ]),
                )),
              );
              
              }
              if (task.date==DateFormat.yMd().format(_selectedDate)){
                return AnimationConfiguration.staggeredList(
                position: index,
                child: SlideAnimation(
                    child: FadeInAnimation(
                  child: Row(children: [
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        _showBottomSheet(
                            context, task);
                      },
                      child: TaskTile(task),
                    )
                  ]),
                )),
              );
              }else{
                return Container();
              };
            }
            );
      }),
    );
  }

  _showBottomSheet(BuildContext context, Task task) {
    Get.bottomSheet(Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
        top: 4,
      ),
      height: task.isCompleted == 1
          ? MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.24
          : MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.32,
      color: Get.isDarkMode ? darkGreyClr : Colors.white,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 6,
            width: 120,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                color: Get.isDarkMode ? Colors.grey[600] : Colors.grey[300]),
          ),
          Spacer(),
          task.isCompleted == 1
              ? Container()
              : _bottomSheetButton(
                  label: 'Task Completed',
                  onTap: () {
                    _taskController.markTaskCompleted(task.id!);
                    Get.back();
                  },
                  clr: primaryClr,
                  context: context,
                ),
          _bottomSheetButton(
            label: 'Delete Task',
            onTap: () {
              _taskController.delete(task);

              Get.back();
            },
            clr: Colors.red[300]!,
            context: context,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 15,
          ),
          _bottomSheetButton(
            label: 'Close',
            onTap: () {
              Get.back();
            },
            clr: Colors.red[300]!,
            isClose: true,
            context: context,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 10,
          )
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }

  _bottomSheetButton(
      {required String label,
      required Function()? onTap,
      required Color clr,
      bool isClose = false,
      required BuildContext context}) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: onTap,
      child: Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4),
        height: 55,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(
              width: 3,
              color: isClose == true
                  ? Get.isDarkMode
                      ? Colors.grey[600]!
                      : Colors.grey[300]!
                  : clr),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
          color: isClose == true ? Colors.transparent : clr,
        ),
        child: Center(
            child: Text(
          label,
          style:
              isClose ? titleStyle : titleStyle.copyWith(color: Colors.white),
        )),
      ),
    );
  }

  _addDateBar() {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, left: 20),
      child: DatePicker(
        DateTime.now(),
        height: 100,
        width: 80,
        initialSelectedDate: DateTime.now(),
        selectionColor: primaryClr,
        selectedTextColor: Colors.white,
        dateTextStyle: GoogleFonts.lato(
            textStyle: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600, color: Colors.grey)),
        dayTextStyle: GoogleFonts.lato(
            textStyle: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600, color: Colors.grey)),
        monthTextStyle: GoogleFonts.lato(
            textStyle: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 14, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600, color: Colors.grey)),
        onDateChange: (date) {

          setState(() {
            _selectedDate = date;
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }

//TaskBar Row
  _addTaskBar() {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20, top: 10),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text(
                  DateFormat.yMMMMd().format(DateTime.now()),
                  style: subHeadingStyle,
                ),
                Text(
                  'Today',
                  style: headingStyle,
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () async {
              await Get.to(() => AddTaskPage());
              _taskController.getTasks();
            },
            child: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 10),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                color: primaryClr,
              ),
              child: Text(
                '+ Add Task',
                style: buttonStyle,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

//Appbar
  _appBar() {
    return AppBar(
      elevation: 0,
      //Strich unter AppBar
      backgroundColor:
          Theme.of(scaffoldContext).backgroundColor, // Aktualisierte Zeile
      leading: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          ThemeService().switchTheme();
          var notifyHelper = NotifyHelper();
          notifyHelper.displayNotification(
              title: 'Theme Changed',
              body: Get.isDarkMode
                  ? 'Activated Light Theme'
                  : 'Activated Dark Theme');

          //notifyHelper.scheduledNotification(); //Notification nach 5 Sekunden
        },
        child: Icon(
          Get.isDarkMode ? Icons.wb_sunny : Icons.nightlight,
          size: 20,
          color: Get.isDarkMode ? Colors.white : Colors.black,
        ),
      ),
      actions: [
        CircleAvatar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/Profile_Picture.jpg'),
        ),
        SizedBox(width: 20),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class ThemeService {
  final _box = GetStorage();
  final _key = 'isDarkMode';
  _saveThemeToBox(bool isDarkMode) => _box.write(_key, isDarkMode);

  bool _loadThemeFromBox() => _box.read(_key) ?? false;
  ThemeMode get theme => _loadThemeFromBox() ? ThemeMode.dark : ThemeMode.light;
  void switchTheme() {
    Get.changeThemeMode(_loadThemeFromBox() ? ThemeMode.light : ThemeMode.dark);
    _saveThemeToBox(!_loadThemeFromBox());
  }
}

class MyButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final String label;
  final Function()? onTap;
  const MyButton({Key? key, required this.label, required this.onTap})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: onTap,
      child: Container(
          width: 120,
          height: 60,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20), color: primaryClr),
          child: Text(
            label,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          )),
    );
  }
}

class AddTaskPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const AddTaskPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<AddTaskPage> createState() => _AddTaskPageState();
}

class _AddTaskPageState extends State<AddTaskPage> {
  final TaskController _taskController = Get.put(TaskController());
  final TextEditingController _titleController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _noteController = TextEditingController();
  DateTime _selectedDate = DateTime.now();
  String _endTime = '9:30 PM'; //hardcoded
  String _startTime = DateFormat('hh:mm a').format(DateTime.now()).toString();
  // 11:15 AM = hh:mm a
  int _selectedRemind = 5;
  List<int> remindList = [
    5,
    10,
    15,
    20,
  ];

  String _selectedRepeat = 'None';
  List<String> repeatList = [
    'None',
    'Daily',
    'Weekly',
    'Monthly',
  ];

  int _selectedColor = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: context.theme.backgroundColor,
      appBar: _appBar(context),
      body: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                MyInputField(
                  title: 'Title',
                  hint: 'Enter your title',
                  controller: _titleController,
                  widget: Container(),
                ),
                MyInputField(
                  title: 'Note',
                  hint: 'Enter your note',
                  controller: _noteController,
                  widget: Container(),
                ),
                MyInputField(
                  title: 'Date',
                  hint: DateFormat.yMd().format(_selectedDate),
                  widget: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 12.0),
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () => _getDateFromUser(context),
                      child: IconTheme(
                        data: IconThemeData(color: Colors.grey),
                        child: Icon(Icons.calendar_month),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: MyInputField(
                        title: 'Start Date',
                        hint: _startTime,
                        widget: IconButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            _getTimeFromUser(isStartTime: true);
                          },
                          icon: Icon(Icons.access_time_rounded),
                          color: Colors.grey,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(width: 12),
                    Expanded(
                      child: MyInputField(
                        title: 'End Date',
                        hint: _endTime,
                        widget: IconButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            _getTimeFromUser(isStartTime: false);
                          },
                          icon: Icon(Icons.access_time_filled),
                          color: Colors.grey,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                MyInputField(
                  title: 'Remind',
                  hint: '$_selectedRemind minutes early',
                  widget: DropdownButton(
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.keyboard_arrow_down,
                      color: Colors.grey,
                    ),
                    iconSize: 32,
                    elevation: 4,
                    underline: Container(
                      height: 0,
                    ),
                    onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                      setState(() {
                        _selectedRemind = int.parse(newValue!);
                      });
                    },
                    style: subTitleStyle,
                    items:
                        remindList.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((int value) {
                      return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                        value: value.toString(),
                        child: Text(value.toString()),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                  ),
                ),
                MyInputField(
                  title: 'Repeat',
                  hint: '$_selectedRepeat',
                  widget: DropdownButton(
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.keyboard_arrow_down,
                      color: Colors.grey,
                    ),
                    iconSize: 32,
                    elevation: 4,
                    underline: Container(
                      height: 0,
                    ),
                    onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                      setState(() {
                        _selectedRepeat = newValue!;
                      });
                    },
                    style: subTitleStyle,
                    items: repeatList
                        .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String? value) {
                      return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                        value: value,
                        child:
                            Text(value!, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey)),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 18,
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    _colorPallete(),
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () => _validateData(),
                      child: Container(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            horizontal: 20, vertical: 10),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                          color: primaryClr,
                        ),
                        child: Text(
                          'Create Task',
                          style: buttonStyle,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  _validateData() {
    if (_titleController.text.isNotEmpty && _noteController.text.isNotEmpty) {
      _addTaskToDb();
      Get.back();
    } else {
      String errorMessage;
      if (_titleController.text.isEmpty && _noteController.text.isEmpty) {
        errorMessage = 'Title and note are required!';
      } else if (_titleController.text.isEmpty) {
        errorMessage = 'Title is required!';
      } else {
        errorMessage = 'Note is required!';
      }

      Get.snackbar(
        'Required',
        errorMessage,
        snackPosition: SnackPosition.BOTTOM,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        colorText: pinkClr,
        icon: Icon(
          Icons.warning_amber_rounded,
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
      );
    }
  }

  _addTaskToDb() async {
    int value = await _taskController.addTask(
        task: Task(
      note: _noteController.text,
      title: _titleController.text,
      date: DateFormat.yMd().format(_selectedDate),
      startTime: _startTime,
      endTime: _endTime,
      remind: _selectedRemind,
      repeat: _selectedRepeat,
      color: _selectedColor,
      isCompleted: 0,
    ));
    print('My id is ' + '$value');
  }

  _colorPallete() {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Text('Color', style: titleStyle),
        SizedBox(
          height: 8.0,
        ),
        //in horizontaler Reihe = Wrap
        Wrap(
            children: List<Widget>.generate(3, (int index) {
          return GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                _selectedColor = index;
              });
            },
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0),
              child: CircleAvatar(
                radius: 14,
                backgroundColor: index == 0
                    ? primaryClr
                    : index == 1
                        ? pinkClr
                        : yellowClr,
                child: _selectedColor == index
                    ? Icon(
                        Icons.done,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        size: 16,
                      )
                    : Container(),
                //Farbauswahl
              ),
            ),
          );
        }))
      ],
    );
  }

  AppBar _appBar(BuildContext context) {
    return AppBar(
      elevation: 0,
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
      leading: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          Get.back();
        },
        child: Icon(
          Icons.arrow_back_ios,
          size: 20,
          color: Get.isDarkMode ? Colors.white : Colors.black,
        ),
      ),
      actions: [
        CircleAvatar(
          backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/Icon2.png'),
        ),
        SizedBox(width: 20),
      ],
    );
  }

  _getDateFromUser(BuildContext context) async {
    DateTime? _pickerDate = await showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: DateTime.now(),
      firstDate: DateTime(2015),
      lastDate: DateTime(2121),
    );

    if (_pickerDate != null) {
      setState(() {
        _selectedDate = _pickerDate;
        print(_selectedDate);
      });
    } else {
      print('It is null or something is wrong');
    }
  }

  _getTimeFromUser({required bool isStartTime}) async {
    var pickedTime = await _showTimePicker(isStartTime);
    if (pickedTime == null) {
      print('Time canceled');
    } else {
      String _formatedTime = pickedTime.format(context);
      if (isStartTime == true) {
        setState(() {
          _startTime = _formatedTime;
        });
      } else {
        setState(() {
          _endTime = _formatedTime;
        });
      }
    }
  }

  _showTimePicker(bool isStartTime) {
    TimeOfDay initialTime;
    if (isStartTime) {
      if (_startTime.isNotEmpty) {
        initialTime = TimeOfDay(
          hour: int.parse(_startTime.split(':')[0]),
          minute: int.parse(_startTime.split(':')[1].split(' ')[0]),
        );
      } else {
        initialTime = TimeOfDay.now();
      }
    } else {
      if (_endTime.isNotEmpty) {
        initialTime = TimeOfDay(
          hour: int.parse(_endTime.split(':')[0]),
          minute: int.parse(_endTime.split(':')[1].split(' ')[0]),
        );
      } else {
        initialTime = TimeOfDay.now();
      }
    }

    return showTimePicker(
      initialEntryMode: TimePickerEntryMode.input,
      context: context,
      initialTime: initialTime,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using  runApp(const CalendarRoute()); in calendar.dart:

Comment: Probably missed it, will delete. Any other problem?

Comment: Too much things in too little files. You should start refactoring your code. Split your widgets in smaller gruops. You should have only 1 main, which will be your entry point.

Comment: Okay will do. But I have only one main. What do you mean?

Comment: I need help how to display the tasks of _showTasks to my main when I open CalendarRoute.

Comment: Also when I copy paste my calendar.dart Code to main.dart it works fine and the tasks get displayed. Just not when I open CalendarRoute through main and add tasks.